# how to fetch data from room Database kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I m new in RoomDatabse. I have to fetch Data from Room database in offline mode.
here is code

Json

```
[
 {"id": 1,
  "name": "Hero",
  "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Sunflower_from_Silesia2.jpg",
  "age": "23"}
]
```

Here is Model

```
class Actor() : ArrayList<ActorItem>()
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "actor",indices = arrayOf(Index(value= arrayOf("id"),unique = true)))
data class ActorItem(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id_:Int,
    @SerializedName("age")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "age")
    val age: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("image")
    @ColumnInfo(name="image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String
)
```

Repository Class

```
class ReposetoryHelper(
    private val actorApi: ActorApi,
    private val databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper,
    private val applicationContext: Context)
{
    private val actorData = MutableLiveData<Actor>()
    val actors : LiveData<Actor>
    get() = actorData

    suspend fun getActor(){
        if(NetworkUtil.isInternetAvailable(applicationContext)){
            //fatch data from API while Online
            val result_ = actorApi.getActor()
            if (result_.body()!=null){
                databaseHelper.actorDao().addActor(result_.body()!!)
                actorData.postValue(result_.body())
            }
        }else{
                //fatch data from Database while Offline
            }
        }
    }
```

Dao Class

```
@Dao
interface ActorDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addActor(actorItem: List<ActorItem>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM actor")
    suspend fun getActor():List<ActorItem>
}
```

so While connected with network data come from API. but now how do i get Data From Database while i lost connection.

Comment: in else part you can write `actorData.postValue(databaseHelper.actorDao().getActor())` is this what you are asking ? Or do you want a listener when network is disconnected ?

Comment: i m doing same as u write but it said required Actor, but found ActorList

Comment: Please also attach error that you are seeing. Attach a screenshot or post the error

Comment: If I am not wrong, The issue is in Rest API response.

Comment: Type mismatch.
Required: Actor!
Found: List<ActorItem>

Comment: yes because `actorData = MutableLiveData<Actor>()` It is a data of Object. If you want to store arraylist or list in a variable you should use `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Actor?>>`

Comment: ya i change my json and its work

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM actor")
fun getActor():LiveData<List<ActorItem>>
```

then you can try

```
 actorDao.getActor().observe(this, Observer<List<ActorItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<ActorItem> actorItemList) {

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ActorItem")
suspend fun getActor():List<ActorItem>
```

Use ActorItem table as a model

actorData.postValue(databaseHelper.actorDao().getActor())
then you will not get the type mismatch error.